# what is __clk_of_table symbol in of_clk_init of linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, clock

I was going through linux kernel 3.10, which has a function `of_clk_init` which is as below

```
void __init of_clk_init(const struct of_device_id *matches)
{
    struct device_node *np;

    if (!matches)
        matches = __clk_of_table;

    for_each_matching_node(np, matches) {
        const struct of_device_id *match = of_match_node(matches, np);
        of_clk_init_cb_t clk_init_cb = match->data;
        clk_init_cb(np);
    }
}
```

when i look for the symbol __clk_of_table i did not find any reference but i am very sure that __clk_of_table has got something to do with the linux device tree model is that ??

Comment: See `include/asm-generic/vmlinux.lds.h`.

Comment: This is what i have found `#define CLK_OF_TABLES() . = ALIGN(8);    
  VMLINUX_SYMBOL(__clk_of_table) = .; 
   *(__clk_of_table)   
   *(__clk_of_table_end)`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `__clk_of_table` reflects the special section in the blob that provides `struct of_device_id` for clocks.

Defined in the **include/linux/clk-provider.h**

```
extern struct of_device_id __clk_of_table;

#define CLK_OF_DECLARE(name, compat, fn) OF_DECLARE_1(clk, name, compat, fn)
```

Comment: when i see my code there are types of  clocks declared(fixed,gated,muxed..) using above macros which make them  present at location `__clk_of_table` further the same kind of clocks are verified with available clocks in device tree(`of_allnodes`) which are further called using `fn` with `np` being parameter ... am i right ? ... is this a valid common clock tree implementation ... correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: I didn't investigate this deep, though you probably right. I don't understand what you meant under _common_ implementation.